# JQuery keyup doesn't trigger, while simply change to click triggers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, keyup

JSFIDDLE here: http://jsfiddle.net/TmXFZ/

What the code does is: If press ALT while hover the table cells, the background color of the cell will change. If hover out or release ALT, the background color of the cell goes back to original.

However, when release the ALT key, the color doesn't change back.

I tried to simply change

```
  $(document).keyup(function() {
```

To

```
  $(document).click(function() {
```

on click, the color change back perfectly.

So why does click triggers but keyup doesn't?

Comment: The keyup works fine. What browser are you using? You have invalid HTML there. You can't have `th` in `tbody`.

Comment: This is working for me as well in Chrome

Comment: I'm using chrome Version 33.0.1750.117 I'll try other browsers

Comment: In firefox on Windows it will open the file/edit/view... toolbar if you hit alt. You should really bind this to another key since alt has way to many uses.

Comment: @easwee You're right. I'll change my code. It turns out that ALT is a hot key for another app which make it behaves odd. Thanks! Problem solved.

Comment: @alexZ Posted it as an answer for future reference - you can accept it or wait if someone posts a way to force an override with js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In firefox on Windows it will open the `file/edit/view...` toolbar if you hit <kbd>alt</kbd>.

You should really bind this to another key since <kbd>alt</kbd> has way to many uses and is a very common shortcut / combo key in many applications.

Answer (score 0):

Think that might be because of how you've structured your code. The method you want to produce is different to just reading the document. Would be good if I could see some code to work with but I ca still build something that might help.

This should work but I have this feeling that `$(this)` will not work on the second 'hover out' function.

```
$('td').mouseOver(function(){
    var td=$(this);
    $(document).keydown(function(keycode,td){
        if(keycode.altKey)$(td).css({'background':'#FF0000'});
    });
    $(document).keyup(function(keycode,td){
        if(keycode.altKey)$(td).css({'background':'#00FF00'});
    });
},function(){
    $(this).css({'background':'#00FF00'});
});
```

Comment: Your feeling is right. The keyup doesn't work every time. It works fine after first hover, but second time hover doesn't work. Then 3rd time works, 4th time doesn't. I'm trying to figure out why.

Comment: @alexZ so if you put the mouse over the element, press alt and then take the mouse out of the element. Does the element change colour? I've had another quick idea. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @alexZ actually I'm really struggling with this! lol I'm still persisting.